# Iterating the bytes of a File is empty after iterating the lines of the same file

Tags: rust

I'm creating something similar to the `wc` command. Counting lines seems to work fine, but counting bytes always returns a 0. Counting words also doesn't work; the output seems to "hang" like it's waiting for something.

I realize that the way it is made (reading the file 3 times over) isn't the most optimal way to do this, but I just want a working and simple example

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Read};

fn main() {
    let arg = &std::env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .expect("No file operand found")
        .to_owned();
    let file = File::open(arg).expect("Unable to open file for reading");

    let lines = count_lines(&file);
    print!("{} ", lines);
    let bytes = count_bytes(&file);
    println!("{}", bytes);
    let words = count_words(&file);
    print!("{} ", words);
}

fn count_lines(file: &File) -> u32 {
    let mut count: u32 = 0;
    BufReader::new(file).lines().for_each(|f| {
        if f.is_ok() {
            count += 1;
        }
    });

    count
}

fn count_bytes(file: &File) -> u32 {
    let mut count: usize = 0;
    BufReader::new(file).bytes().for_each(|f| {
        if f.is_ok() {
            count += 1;
        }
    });

    count as u32
}

fn count_words(file: &File) -> u32 {
    let mut count: u32 = 0;

    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
    while let Ok(_) = reader.read_until(b' ', &mut buf) {
        count += 1;
    }

    count
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you open the file once, read the complete file and then assume that it will be reset magically.

A `File` has a position "pointer" to know which byte to read next. After you have read one byte, that position will be incremented by one, so the next read call will read the next byte and not the same one.

You can change this position by using [`File::seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#tymethod.seek) between your calls to `count_lines`, `count_bytes` and `count_words`.

```rust
use std::io::{Seek, SeekFrom};

fn main() {
    let arg = &std::env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .expect("No file operand found")
        .to_owned();
    let mut file = File::open(arg).expect("Unable to open file for reading");

    let lines = count_lines(&file);
    print!("{} ", lines);

    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0)).expect("Seek failed");
    let bytes = count_bytes(&file);
    println!("{}", bytes);

    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0)).expect("Seek failed");
    let words = count_words(&file);
    print!("{} ", words);
}
```

---

To further address your code, it is not considered very "rusty". Your manual counting can be simplified by using [`Iterator::count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count).

```rust
fn count_lines(file: &File) -> u32 {
    BufReader::new(file).lines().count() as u32
}

fn count_bytes(file: &File) -> u32 {
    BufReader::new(file).bytes().count() as u32
}
```

---

The reason why your `count_words` function "hangs" is because you ignore the amount of read bytes. When `read_until` reaches EOF (end of file) it will return `0` as amount. You have to introduce a break condition, e.g.

```rust
fn count_words(file: &File) -> u32 {
    let mut count: u32 = 0;

    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
    while let Ok(amount) = reader.read_until(b' ', &mut buf) {
        if amount == 0 {
            break
        }
        count += 1;
    }

    count
}
```

Please note, that this is implementation is not really correct, because `"hello  "` (two spaces at the end) will give you `2` instead of `1`, but this is up to you to fix. Make sure to [add some tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-00-testing.html) to make sure everything works correctly.

Comment: To be honest, I've always found this confusing; wish it was named FileCursor to make it clearer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you might be right, but AFAIK every language works this way (probably due to how linux handles files). This is something that needs to be learnt, I'm afraid ^^